# How to add gradient border only to the top and bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to add a gradient border (from black to grey) only to my top and bottom borders and none to the edges.

Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
border-top: 10px solid red;
border-bottom: 10px solid red;
border-left-width: 0;
border-right-width: 0;
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, violet) 1 stretch;
```

border-right-width and border-left-width are required for Chrome and Safari.